# How to change output directory in Sapper + Rollup?

Tags: rollupjs, svelte, sapper

I tried changing `rollup.config.js` to say

```js
output: {...config.client.output(), dir: __dirname}
```

It put some stuff in `__dirname`, some stuff in `./__sapper__`, then it threw errors and died. Setting the `build --output` flag only sets the intermediate file output directory. Do I just have to let it output to the default folder then copy it post build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `sapper build my-output-directory`.

Comment: Oh, haha. I just did `sapper build --help` again and noticed this little line: `Usage: sapper build [dest] [options]`. Totally skipped right past that and was only looking at options. Cheers.